# AngularJS ui-router omitting query parameters

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I need to switch to a new state in my AngularJS app. I am using ui-router to manage the states. The current URL contains query parameters that I use. The URL for the new state should not contain those query parameters. I tried setting the inherit option to false in calls to both $state.go and $state.transitionTo, but neither removed the query parameters. Is that another way to do this?

Comment: This sounds like something `ui.router` definitely does not do. Could you post a Plunkr that reproduces the behavior so we could see it in action?

Comment: I started creating a Plunkr, but realized I can't demonstrate the problem in that way.  The idea is that the Angular app is accessed with a URL that contains query parameters.  I need to process those and remove them from the URL on app startup.  Daniel Tabuenca suggested that I try using the History API.  That worked for me.  In the function I pass to app.config() I just call this: history.replaceState(null, null, '/');

Comment: Okay, but you should really be using the `$location` service.